# PowerShell - How to convert a powershell script to a GUI with checkboxes

Tags: powershell

I have a script with functions that I call them according to an order. the issue is that sometime I want to disable some of them and I don't want to insert # before the name of the function. I want to convert it to the GUI and let the user to choose with checkboxes the relevant function to run.
I don't know what the option that I have or tools, maybe someone can let me a start or even an example how to do it
Thanks
I have an example I found but it cannot call functions (Only print a string)
and also I want to use the real powershell console. just choose the relevant checkboxes and run the script as usual

```
function GenerateForm {

[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing") | Out-Null

$form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$listBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$checkBox3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$checkBox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$checkBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState

$b1= $false
$b2= $false
$b3= $false

#----------------------------------------------
#Generated Event Script Blocks
#----------------------------------------------

$handler_button1_Click= 
{
    $listBox1.Items.Clear();    

    if ($checkBox1.Checked)     {  $listBox1.Items.( "Checkbox 1 is checked"  ) }

    if ($checkBox2.Checked)    {  $listBox1.Items.Add( "Checkbox 2 is checked"  ) }

    if ($checkBox3.Checked)    {  $listBox1.Items.Add( "Checkbox 3 is checked"  ) }

    if ( !$checkBox1.Checked -and !$checkBox2.Checked -and !$checkBox3.Checked ) {   $listBox1.Items.Add("No CheckBox selected....")} 
}

$OnLoadForm_StateCorrection=
{#Correct the initial state of the form to prevent the .Net maximized form issue
    $form1.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
}

#----------------------------------------------
#region Generated Form Code
$form1.Text = "AutoSideVip"
$form1.Name = "AutoSideVip"
$form1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 1000
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 500
$form1.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size

$button1.TabIndex = 4
$button1.Name = "button1"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 75
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 23
$button1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True

$button1.Text = "Run Script"

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 27
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 156
$button1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$button1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$button1.add_Click($handler_button1_Click)

$form1.Controls.Add($button1)

$listBox1.FormattingEnabled = $True
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 800
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 450
$listBox1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$listBox1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$listBox1.Name = "listBox1"
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 137
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 13
$listBox1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$listBox1.TabIndex = 3

$form1.Controls.Add($listBox1)


$checkBox3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 104
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 24
$checkBox3.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$checkBox3.TabIndex = 2
$checkBox3.Text = "CheckBox 3"
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 27
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 75
$checkBox3.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$checkBox3.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$checkBox3.Name = "checkBox3"

$form1.Controls.Add($checkBox3)


$checkBox2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 104
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 24
$checkBox2.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$checkBox2.TabIndex = 1
$checkBox2.Text = "CheckBox 2"
$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 27
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 44
$checkBox2.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$checkBox2.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$checkBox2.Name = "checkBox2"

$form1.Controls.Add($checkBox2)



    $checkBox1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
    $System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
    $System_Drawing_Size.Width = 104
    $System_Drawing_Size.Height = 24
    $checkBox1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
    $checkBox1.TabIndex = 0
    $checkBox1.Text = "CheckBox 1"
    $System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
    $System_Drawing_Point.X = 27
    $System_Drawing_Point.Y = 13
    $checkBox1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
    $checkBox1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
    $checkBox1.Name = "checkBox1"

$form1.Controls.Add($checkBox1)


#Save the initial state of the form
$InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
#Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
$form1.add_Load($OnLoadForm_StateCorrection)
#Show the Form
$form1.ShowDialog()| Out-Null

} #End Function

#Call the Function
GenerateForm
```

I have many function to call

```
Clear-Host
StartTranscript # Writing to log
connectTFS #Connect to TFS 
ChooseVersion # Choose version to work on
Createtempfolders # Create temp folders
Gathercontent # Gather new content
#Copyfilesforautomation #Copy the latest files for automation
RunCI # Run CI automation
CreateTFS # Create TFS item
StartingRelease # Create a new release
CloseTfs # Close TFS item
FinalizeSheet # Finalize the sheet
Createemail # Create a new email
UndoExcelChanges # Undo the last changes 
RunWeekendAutomation # Copy the build for weekend automation
```

Comment: You could create a `system.Windows.Forms.Form` with checkboxes to specify which functions are called, however it may be easier to just use function parameters and create a main wrapper function to specify which functions are to be called each time via user input in the console when the function is called.  It would be easier to provide feedback if you had an example minimal script to build comments on top of.

Comment: I update the question

Comment: While the example you found and posted may not call a function, you can call a function and have it return output to be stored in a variable (or displayed in a textbox or similar GUI component).  It sounds like all you really want or need is a wrapper function that allows you to specify which functions to call on that run.  If someone else doesn't suggest a template, I will come back after-hours and add a suggestion that may be of help.  Would have to think about it for a bit.

Comment: Thank you I am waiting :)

Comment: Anyone?
I need a wrapper function that allows me to specify which functions to call while running the script.